# NodeJS: How to create sym link for a directory

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, symlink

I am running kue node module in my app. Kue has its own UI. To use that UI we do this.

```
app.use(kue.app);
```

What that does it that it treats kue modules directory as my default directory. But I also want to use some custom routes to render and serve some pages of my own.

My custom templates reside in. **/*app-directory*/views/**

And the JS/CSS files reside in **/*app-directory*/public/)**

The issue is now that when I try to include any JS/CSS file in my jade template it is trying to look for that in public folder of the kue module.

**/*app-directory*/node_modules/kue/lib/http/public/**

I was suggested to create a symlink folder in kue's public folder that links it to main app's public folder. But I have never done that before, and can't seem to find any tutorial on google. So it would be great if someone can help out here or point to a link.

I don't know if it matters but the server is running on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: `sudo ln -s TARGET LINK_NAME`, e.g. `sudo ln -s /path/to/file /path/to/symlink`

Comment: @Ravi Is it possible to symlink a complete directory?

Comment: yes, don't give them any any relative path (i.e `~/Data`). Specify the  full path.

Comment: Cool. Will try that tonight. Will ping you if it worked and then we mark it is an answer.